# Node.js project using ts-node has long compile speed using Docker Windows 11 (WSL2)

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, ts-node

Running into long compile times using docker desktop, roughly 30 seconds.

Running the project locally is fast, roughly 2-3 seconds.

Updated wsl2 config:

```
[wsl2] 
memory=4000MB    #Limits VM memory in WSL 2 to 4000MB 
processors=4    #Makes the WSL 2 VM use four virtual processors
```

Anyone else have this issue?

Docker Compose File:

```
version: "3.4"
name: "node-app"
services:
  # Node api service
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    command: npm run dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 8800:8800
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app

  # Mongodb service
  mongodb:
    container_name: node-app-mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null

  # Redis service
  redis:
    container_name: node-app-redis
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data

volumes:
  mongo_data: {}
  redis_data: {}
```